# Do I need to sanitize user input before posting to query_posts?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, xss

I'm taking over dev of a plugin and they've pretty much got a 1 to 1 mapping of front end JavaScript to back end `query_posts` via ajax.

Is it safe here or do I need to escape everything/certain fields?

edit: the reason I ask is `parse_query` contains a bunch of sanitization already. I could create a complete duplicate of that code in my plugin, but that just seems a bit silly/pointless? and the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts docs don't mention anything about providing sanitized input

Cheers

Comment: sanitize all user input, period...

Comment: I am sorry to say, but if you ask this question you should not take over the dev of a plugin :-) . Kidding apart - like @David mentioned -  you should always always sanitize, and sanitize a lot and sanitize early. Can you please list the `cons` of sanitizing excluding factors like `~laziness~` and `~I believe that nothing can happen~` ? Just for personal interest - I would be interested in knowing those `cons` for future reference .who knows - maybe you are right and I can learn why not to sanitize.

Comment: @ObmerkKronen the reason I ask is `parse_query` contains a bunch of sanitization already. I could create a complete duplicate of that code in my plugin,  but that just seems a bit silly/pointless? and the https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts docs don't mention anything about providing sanitized input.

Comment: The pasrse_query contains general sanitation, not specific ones to your ( unknown ) case or data type . The docs do not mention that because it assumes that programmers will do that .I suggest you read [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) and also [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data). So the answer to your direct question is simply " YES " .

Comment: Just to add, you should **never** use `query_posts`, it is slow, rerun queries and most importantly, breaks the main query object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parse_query` contains general sanitation, not specific ones to your ( unknown ) case or data type validation. The docs do not mention that because it assumes that programmers will do that .
The CODEX is a great tool - that I use every day, but you must understand that it is not 100% correct, nor completed . It is more of a specific guidlines .

The rest is up to one`s common sense.

I suggest you read [HERE](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) and also [HERE‌](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation)​ if you want codex reference for data sanitation and validation - and also for a list of specific data type functions that are built-in into wordpress.

So the answer to your direct question is simply " YES " . you should sanitize / escape , and "NO" , you should assume it is not safe ( even if it is, or you assume that it is  ) .